# Rails 4- why decimal column values are getting rounded off in Postgres - used to store latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding, rails-geocoder

In my Rails 4 application with Postgres DB, My Application takes an address of the vendor and shows in on the map, which should be precise. To Geocode, I am using `geocoder gem`.But no matter what I do, the values of latitude/Longitude are always stored by getting rounded off, ignoring the precision/scale specified in the migration file.

```
###migration file - addresses table===========================
      t.text :address_1
      t.text :landmark
      t.text :street
      t.string :city,add_index:true
      t.string :state,add_index:true
      t.string :zipcode
      t.string :country,add_index:true
      t.string :country_code
      t.string :slug, index:true
      ##special care for geospatial coordinates
      t.decimal :latitude, {:precision=>15, :scale=>15}
      t.decimal :longitude, {:precision=>15, :scale=>15}
      t.boolean :active,:default=>true

##in address.rb===============================================
geocoded_by :address_1
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.street = geo.formatted_address
    obj.state   = geo.state
    obj.city    = geo.city
    obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
    obj.country = geo.country
    obj.country_code = geo.country_code
  end
end
after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode ,:if => :address_1_changed?
```

> ```
> But every time, the values are rounded off to a precision of 6.For example - 
> Even if I try to update the latitude/longitude manually through the console.
> ```
>
> I am unable to get the dedicated values as defined in my
>   migration file(precision and scale of 15)

```
##in rails console
 2.4.1 :003 > Address.last.update_attributes(:longitude => "73.1338649019608")                                                                                                                    
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
    blah blah blah
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
2.4.1 :004 > Address.last.longitude.to_s
 => "73.133864902" 
##values are rounded off :(
```

Is there an issue with Geocoder or is there something wrong with Postgres.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt this is a problem with postgres and you haven't hit the ruby limit on decimals, so I suspect that geocoder is automatically rounding it for you. I am curious to why you need this precision.  On the geocoder readme they provide this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Accuracy which shows that a decimal with a scale of 8 decimal places provides a precision into the millimeters.

Comment: I am displaying the locations on the map using the lat/lng, so when I update the location, its not exactly at the same point, but moves away to nearby points due to the rounding off.Thats why i need exact location and its lat/lng to be shown on the map.

Comment: Hmm, I have been looking into this more.  Are you using any specific geocoder lookup (i.e. google)? Or are using the default?